# Create Date Range from Two Dates/Timestamps?

Tags: java, date

How can a range of dates be obtained if two end dates are known?

I.E. If I want all dates between `2015-06-07 00:00:00` and `2015-01-01 00:00:00`, how can I do this if both dates have already been made into `Date` or `Timestamp` objects?

I know this is possible in Python, using the `datetime` module:

```
[str(end_date + timedelta(days=x)) for x in range((start_date-end_date).days + 1)]
```

What is the equivalent in Java?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534924/how-to-iterate-through-range-of-dates-in-java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.util.Calendar` approach:

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.setTime(startDate);
Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.setTime(endDate);

for (Date date = start.getTime(); start.before(end); start.add(Calendar.DATE, 1), date = start.getTime()) {
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

`java.time.LocalDate` approach (requires `Java 8`):

```
LocalDate start = startDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
LocalDate end = endDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

for (LocalDate date = start; date.isBefore(end); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! Its great that this can be implemented using standard java libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Using Joda:

```
LocalDate from = new LocalDate(fromDate);
LocalDate to = new LocalDate(toDate);
int nDays = Days.daysBetween(from, to).getDays();

List<Date> days = new ArrayList<>(nDays);
for(int i = 0 ; i <= nDays ; i++) {
    days.add(from.plusDays(i).toDate());
}
```

Or in Java 8:

```
final LocalDate from = new LocalDate(fromDate);
final LocalDate to = new LocalDate(toDate);
List<Date> days = IntStream.range(0, Days.daysBetween(from, to).getDays() + 1)
                           .map(i -> from.plusDays(i).toDate())
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```