# Java: How to iterate over days in a Period object

Tags: java

If I have a Period object defined like this:

```
Period.between(LocalDate.of(2015,8,1), LocalDate.of(2015,9,2))
```

how to iterate over all days starting from first day until the last one? I need a loop that has an object `LocalDate` referring to the current date to process it.

Comment: And to iterate given the two dates, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534924/how-to-iterate-through-range-of-dates-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though Jon Skeet's answer is the right answer, an easy workaround would be

```
LocalDate currentStart=LocalDate.from(start);
LocalDate currentEnd=LocalDate.from(end.plusDays(1));//end is inclusive
do{
    // do what you want with currentStart
    //....
    currentStart=currentStart.plusDays(1);
}while (!currentStart.equals(currentEnd));
```

Answer (score 6):

As Jon Skeet explained, you cannot do this with `java.time.Period`. It is simply not an interval. There is no anchor on the date line. But you have start and end, so this is possible:

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2015, 8, 1);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2015, 9, 2);
Stream<LocalDate> stream = 
    LongStream
        .range(start.toEpochDay(), end.toEpochDay() + 1) // end interpreted as inclusive
        .mapToObj(LocalDate::ofEpochDay);
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
2015-08-01
2015-08-02
2015-08-03
...
2015-08-31
2015-09-01
2015-09-02
```

Comment: Is this going to increment over every long value until it gets a new day?

Comment: @M-T-A Over every long value? Yes, but only between start and end, not the whole long-range ;-) Basically this is the algorithm which is planned for new stream support for `LocalDate` in Java-9 via new proposed method `datesUntil(end)`, see also https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146218.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new way in Java 9. You can obtain `Stream<LocalDate>` of days between start and end.

```
start
  .datesUntil(end)
  .forEach(it -> out.print(“ > “ + it));
--
> 2017–04–14 > 2017–04–15 > 2017–04–16 > 2017–04–17 > 2017–04–18 > 2017–04–19
```

[You can read more here](https://medium.com/@ggajos/jdk9-iterate-days-with-localdate-datesuntil-db5d73ec3545).

Answer (score 2):

You can't - because a `Period` doesn't know its start/end dates... it *only* knows how long it is in terms of years, months, days etc. In that respect, it's a sort of calendar-centric version of `Duration`.

If you want to create your own, it would be easy to do, of course - but I don't believe there's anything out of the box in either `java.time` (or Joda Time, as it happens) to do this.