# How to change a date in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, date

I have worked on a loan installment calculator in Java swing.
How do I get 6 month dates if I make 6 month installments.
I want this scenario in Java swing. How do I get 6, 8, 10 month dates in loop in Java swing?

[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i < date.length; i++) { // cycle #1: over all initialized dates
    for (int j = 0; j < 40; i++) {      // cycle #2: 40 repeats for each date
        date[i].nextDay();
        System.out.print("Incremented Date:" + date[i].toString());
    }
```

Comment: Welcome Naveed. Have you consider google **java calendar add month** ?

Comment: Question is not clear for me. What is this 40? What are the objects you use in `date` array? `java.util.Date` objects?

Comment: I suggest you stay away from `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date`. They are **old**. Look into `LocalDate` and perhaps `YearMonth` of [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Possible near-duplicate of [How to iterate through range of Dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534924/how-to-iterate-through-range-of-dates-in-java). Just like `LocalDate` has a `plusDays` method used in some of the answers there it also has a `plusMonths` method that you may use to your advantage.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not really clear to me, but you may mean something like the following?

```
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.FEBRUARY, 1);
    int months = 10;

    LocalDate currentDate = startDate;
    for (int i = 0; i < months; i++) {
        System.out.println(currentDate);
        currentDate = currentDate.plusMonths(1);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> 2019-02-01
> 2019-03-01
> 2019-04-01
> 2019-05-01
> 2019-06-01
> 2019-07-01
> 2019-08-01
> 2019-09-01
> 2019-10-01
> 2019-11-01
> ```

Comment: Yes!, i want to make student installment plane for exmple if a student semster fee is 20000K and he want to make installment in 6 months , 20K installment for he make 5 installments then how we are genrate date with installments like 1st 01/02/2019, 2nd 01/02/2019 and so on 5..