# Problem to get a map with interval of date as key

Tags: java, date, hashmap

I have a list of ballon. A ballon have a fields dateCreation and color.
And I have two dates called dateStart and dateEnd that the user chose.

I need to have a Map where the key are all the date between dateStart and dateEnf, and where the value depend of the date of the ballon.

For exemple :

- if the date of the user are:
   **2019-01-01** and **2019-01-05**
- if I have 4 ballon b1:
  **b1.dateCreation = 2019-01-01

  b2.dateCreation = 2019-01-02

  b3.dateCreation = 2019-01-04

  b4.dateCreation = 2019-01-04**

I want to have this map
**<2019-01-01, [b1]>

<2019-01-02, [b2]>

<2019-01-03, []>

<2019-01-04 [b3, b4]>

<2019-01-05, []>**

For the moment I have this methode

```
public Map<Date, Ballon[]> getMapOfBallonByDate(Date dateStart, Date dateEnd) {
        List<Ballon> allBallonInTheDateInterval = ticketRepository.findTicketByDate(dateStart, dateEnd);
        ...
        return ...
}
```

I don't know what to write in the body of the function. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Date, List<Balloon>> allBalloonInTheDateInterval = ticketRepository.findTicketByDate(dateStart, dateEnd)
.stream()
.collect(groupingBy(Balloon::getDateCreation));
```

Create a new map `Map<Date, Balloon[]> balloonMap = new HashMap<>();`

Then you can iterate over the date range. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535239/7155432

In each iteration,

```
Balloon[] currentBalloons = allBalloonInTheDateInterval1.getOrDefault(currentIterationDate, new ArrayList<>()).toArray(new Balloon[0]);
balloonMap.put(currentIterationDate, currentBalloons);
```

Comment: Fine suggestion. Only I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It also makes iteration a lot more straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! Can you explain me what does mine this line Balloon::getDateCreation, because I dont understand how getDateCreation can return the Date.

And when I create the allBalloonInTheDateInterval, how can I do for the ballon date that is retrieved only contain days, months and years. Because I think the hours and seconds are a problem for the rest.
I think I need to do it because when I do this line 
`Balloon[] currentBalloons = allBalloonInTheDateInterval1.getOrDefault(currentIterationDate, new ArrayList<>()).toArray(new Balloon[0]);`
I have no ballon in the map

Comment: As suggested on above comment, could you use LocalDate if time is not required?

Comment: Yes I can use it. But then I do not know what to do